# How to persist check-box checked - MVC/JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm using MVC framework and on my page i have few checkbox and based on the checkbox user checked i'm showing the div with input/buttons etc... but when the user post the page and if the page has any errors it refresh the entire page and my selection is gone and again i have to check the checkbox to show the div.

My question is how can I persist the selection? How do I update the selection in this case the selection is which checkbox is checked and update the property in the controller `EmployeeChk`

I have tried something like this:

.Model class

```
property bool EmployeeChk {get; set;}
property bool EmployerChk {get;set;}
```

//View page:

```
<table width="auto">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Employee
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBox("Employee")
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>

<fieldset id="emp" style="@(Model.EmployeeChk ? "" : "display: none")" class="fieldset-auto-width">
<legend>
    <legend>
        Employee Display
    </legend>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeServer", "EmployeeForm", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div>..... </div>

    }

</fieldset>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#Employee').change(function() {
            if (this.checked) { 
                $('#emp').show();
            }  
        });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Bind your checkbox to the `EmployeeChk` property - `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeChk)` (and change the script to `$('#EmployeeChk').change(..`

Comment: its not that straight-forward, I have demo here https://dotnetfiddle.net/wVtwgW my problem please have a look

Comment: You model does not even have properties for `bool EmployeeChk` so not sure what you really asking here. And since you only have one model (`Person`) posting back to the same controller method, I don't understand what you trying to do here

Comment: And why are you using checkboxes anyway - you should be using radio buttons and get rid of the script - its not necessary at all

Comment: I was trying to mimic the problem I'm having and if you want to see what I have posted here

Comment: Let me fork the fiddle and see I can achieve what I thin you want

Comment: You probably want something like [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZGcqv0), but really, this is the wrong approach

Comment: let me play with it, thanks

Comment: I just did it to show how it could do it. But its not how you should do it :)

Comment: okay got it and its great... I have tweak little bit what I did was for the Employee I have added `@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeReceiveServer", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` and created a `Action Method` in the controller and the purpose of that is to test to see once you get the data you store that into db, however when I post it the page is blank here is the revisied version https://dotnetfiddle.net/UV4sMP - please post as answer I will accept that as well :)

Comment: You get a blank page on the fiddle because you can only have one post method and one view (its a limitation of the site). But I wont post an answer because this is the wrong approach. DON'T DO IT! You have not given enough information to understand what you really need to do but rendering 3 forms on the page when you only post 1 is awful. One option would be to handle the radio buttons click event and use ajax to call a method which returns the relevant form as a partial view and add it to the DOM (but hard to say if this is the best approach with the limited information)

Comment: i'm not sure i'm following you but if you are in a impression that I'm posting all three forms at once then that's absolutely incorrect, again at any given time the user will only be able to post the form one at a time NOT THREE forms , so again just to recap you have three checkbox/radiobutton and user have only choice to click once at a time and post the form one at a time, i hope i clear your doubts.

Comment: I know exactly what your doing (your rendering 3 forms and posting one of them based on the selected person type)

Comment: yes so what's wrong with that approach?, i like to know and other alternative based on your experience.

Comment: 1. Because your rendering 3 times as much html as you need (degrading performance). 2. You have only one model so you should only have one controller (that model/view model should probably contain a property indicating if the person is a Employee or Employer or Contractor - but its not clear why you would need to save the same object in different tables). In any case you should only be posting back to one controller method and then based on the person type do you save.

Comment: i agreed what you said in terms of performance and my html is not huge but in any case, do not hung on too much on the model i have in the .netfiddle that was just a proof of concept to show the problem so now you have understand very well what i am trying to achieve and based on your explanation it sounded that i should only have one controller one view and one model but how will you tackle the situation i have in my case where i have to show three different views based on the selection?

Comment: As noted previously, you could handle the radio buttons click event and use ajax to call a method which returns the appropriate partial view and add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1: When the post is invalid, save the selected checkboxes in the model (variable), and send that model to View. In page load, check if the model has selected checkboxes (from the previous post), if so, update your View. This approach can be hard and annoying to use.

2: Use ajax post instead of normal post. Send your form by ajax, if the post was unsuccessful, just show the error information to the user (the entire page remains the same). If the post was successful, redirect to the desired URL.